# Howe to add opacity when change object property

Tags: javascript, anime.js

i have next example https://codepen.io/mihail-kuznecow/pen/mjoYzz

It's animejs library, https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime.
Codesnippet example:

```js
 const members = [{
        name: "Вася Пупки"
    }, {
        name: "Дмитрий Васильев"
    }, {
        name: "Анатолий Вассерман"
    }, {
        name: "Петросян Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Гоша Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Миша Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Саша Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Анатолий Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Энакентий Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Динис Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Иван Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Руслан Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Богдан Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Костян Вазгенович"
    }];
window.onload = function() {
    const button = document.getElementById('start');

    if(button){
        button.addEventListener('click', () => rollNames(document.querySelector('.name'), members));
    }



    function rollNames(domNode, names) {
        const animatedName = {value: 0};
        let name;
        if (domNode) {
            anime({
                targets: [animatedName, domNode],
                value: names.length - 1,
                round: 1,
                easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
                duration: 5000,
                update: function(a) {
                    if(name != names[animatedName.value].name) {
                        a.animatables[1].target.style.opacity = 0;
                    }else{
                        a.animatables[1].target.style.opacity = 1;
                    }

                    domNode.innerText = names[animatedName.value].name;
                    name = names[animatedName.value].name;
                }
            });

          
            //return anime.finished;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
    <div class="name">
        Hello!
    </div>
</div>

<button id="start">Start roll</button>
```

You can see, name change with flash, i would like to this flash was changed smoothly for each name.

Maybe I should take callbacks or timeline, but all my attempts are not successful.

How i can do it?

Comment: Can't load the codepen. Infinite loading

Comment: he forget a } at the end of the js

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while, but I think I finally have something that you were looking for. You will have to mess around with it a little bit more to get it perfect but I think it's pretty close to what you were asking. The few things I changed was the easing to linear and the duration to 14000 (14 names, 1 name per second). I then used jquery's animate to have a sort of fade in/fade out for each name. You will have to tweak the timing a little but I think basically it is a good example of what you were asking (I hope). Also, here is the modified codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjZYWM

```js
 const members = [{
        name: "Вася Пупки"
    }, {
        name: "Дмитрий Васильев"
    }, {
        name: "Анатолий Вассерман"
    }, {
        name: "Петросян Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Гоша Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Миша Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Саша Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Анатолий Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Энакентий Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Динис Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Иван Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Руслан Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Богдан Вазгенович"
    }, {
        name: "Костян Вазгенович"
    }];
window.onload = function() {
    const button = document.getElementById('start');

    if(button){
        button.addEventListener('click', () => rollNames(document.querySelector('.name'), members));
    }
    function rollNames(domNode, names) {
        const animatedName = {value: 0};
        let name;
        if (domNode) {
            anime({
                targets: [animatedName, domNode],
                value: names.length - 1,
                round: 1,
                easing: 'linear',
                duration: 14000,
                update: function(a) {
                   if(name != names[animatedName.value].name) {
                    $(a.animatables[1].target).animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 500)
                      if(a.animatables[1].target.style.opacity > 0 ){  
                      $(a.animatables[1].target).animate({opacity:'-=1'}, 500) //fades out
                      }
                      else{
                         $(a.animatables[1].target).animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 500)//fades in
                         $(a.animatables[1].target).animate({opacity:'-=1'}, 500)//fades out
                      }
                    }
                    else{
    
                    }

                    domNode.innerText = names[animatedName.value].name;
                    name = names[animatedName.value].name;
                }
            });

          
            //return anime.finished;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="test">
    <div class="name">
    </div>
</div>
<button id="start">Start roll</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this example, unfortunately this is not exactly what I would like, because there is no effect that I really need **easing: 'easeInOutCirc'**
Flash effect must be to time whow change name.

Comment: Your question was how to make the transition from name to name smooth. With the settings in your example, the transition between names becomes too fast for it be smooth. 5 seconds to cycle through 14 names and non-linear will never be smooth because there isn't enough time for it to be smooth. As I put in my example, 14 seconds at one name per second is enough time for there to be a smooth fade-in/fade-out effect for each name.